# Data not retrived if reference table valus is not present in Mysql 8.x.x (Used Theta style join)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like X,Y,Z here table X is the parent table and Y,Z is the child tables. While retrieving parent table X using theta join syntax it showing null values and child tables doesn't have the reference values. The same is working when I am using MySQL 5.7

This is for a new RHEL 8, running MySQL 8.0.13, In the past, I’ve tried on existing Mysql 5.7 it fetching the results.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT aiv.columaiv_id) AS COUNT,ad.* 
  FROM Z aiv,Y ai,X ad 
 WHERE aiv.columaiv_id=ai.columai_id
   AND ai.columai_id=ad.columad_id 
   AND ad.columad_id =10;
```

Comment: You probably need a left join, which is hard to write using the old school join syntax you are using.  Commas in the `FROM` clause = evil.

Comment: *"While retrieving parent table X using theta join syntax it showing null values and child tables doesn't have the reference values. The same is working when I am using MySQL 5.7"* i very much doubt that sounds like @TimBiegeleisen suggested you most likely need `LEFT JOIN` which the comma join syntax simply does not support as it only support INNER JOIN and CROSS JOIN..  See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please use modern `JOIN` syntax available since SQL-92. Theta style joins are error prone and difficult to debug. Plus is tricky to perform outer joins with them.

Comment: Sample data and expected results, please.